# How to set left margin for RelativeLayout Programmatically Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to set the left margin for first `RelativeLayout`, and
I have this `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/market_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/market_linear_layout_in_hsv">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this java code insert in `LinearLayout` with `id = market_linear_layout_in_hsv` inserting `RelativeLayout` including some view `(Button, TextView, ImageView)`:

```
    market_ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.market_linear_layout_in_hsv);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TVParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RLwrapContent, RLwrapContent );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams IVParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 400);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams BParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RLwrapContent, RLwrapContent);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RLParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RLMatchParent, RLMatchParent);

    TVParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    TVParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    IVParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    IVParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    BParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    BParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    if (folder.exists()) {
        String[] files = folder.list();
        relationsIdMarket = new ArrayList<RelationsIdMarket>(files.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            RLParams.setMargins(i == 0?150:0, 0, 0, 0);//here i set on first iteration left margin 150

            RelationsIdMarket rim = new RelationsIdMarket();

            rim.idProduct = i;
            rim.idTextView = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();
            rim.idImageView = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();
            rim.idButton = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("name");

            tv.setId(rim.idTextView);

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            if(GeneralData.images.size() == i)
                GeneralData.images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImg+"/"+files[i]));

            iv.setImageBitmap(GeneralData.images.get(i));

            iv.setId(rim.idImageView);
            iv.setImageBitmap(rp.bmp);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("open");
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn.setId(rim.idButton);

            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

            rl.addView(tv, TVParams);
            rl.addView(iv, IVParams);
            rl.addView(btn, BParams);
            rl.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);

            market_ll.addView(rl, RLParams);

            relationsIdMarket.add(rim);
        }
    }
```

But I haven't been able to get this working. Any help is appreciated.
I am corrected my code as follows:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(RLMatchParent, RLMatchParent);


        if (folder.exists()) {
            String[] files = folder.list();
            relationsIdMarket = new ArrayList<RelationsIdMarket>(files.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                mlp.leftMargin = i==0?100:0;

                RelationsIdMarket rim = new RelationsIdMarket();

                rim.idProduct = i;
                rim.idTextView = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();
                rim.idImageView = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();
                rim.idButton = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Название");

                tv.setId(rim.idTextView);

                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                if(GeneralData.images.size() == i)
                    GeneralData.images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImg+"/"+files[i]));

                iv.setImageBitmap(GeneralData.images.get(i));

                iv.setId(rim.idImageView);
                iv.setImageBitmap(rp.bmp);

                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setText("Открыть");
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);

                btn.setId(rim.idButton);

                RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

                rl.addView(tv, TVParams);
                rl.addView(iv, IVParams);
                rl.addView(btn, BParams);
                rl.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);

                market_ll.addView(rl, mlp);

                relationsIdMarket.add(rim);
            }
        }
```

But The problem is not solved.

Comment: Please post your logcat here.

Comment: and where is your RelativeLayout in the XML?

Comment: My RelativeLayout created Programmatically

Answer (score -1):

Use `android:layout_marginLeft` within your first linear layout.
`Android RelativeLayout` inherits from `android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` which provides methods to set margins for layouts.
Ref [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: but I create RelativeLayout  and not linear layout. Or i don't understand you.

Comment: does not matter your relative layout views can have margins as well

Comment: i fix my code like this:
`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(RLMatchParent, RLMatchParent);
mlp.leftMargin = i==0?100:0;
RelationsIdMarket rim = new RelationsIdMarket();
.............................
market_ll.addView(rl, mlp);`
but, it did not help